# When do you use 'para' and when do you use 'por'?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, orden-de-palabras

How do you know when to use 'para' and when do you use 'por'?

Comment: A native speaker has learned them as two separate words with two separate meanings.  The fact that either one, in context, might be translated into English as "for" is not relevant to the native speaker.

Comment: I noticed that in some cases even native speakers get confused... It is comparable to the French 'pour' and 'par', but even not always equivalent.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/34/376