# salir de versus salir para

Tags: preposiciones

I have to find the correct preposicion for the following example:

"Han salido *1* Paris *2* coche *3* poder llevar mucho equipaje"

1: para
2: en
3: para

I totally understand 2 and 3, but I can't get my head around why it's salir para instead of salir de. Unfortunately I couldn't find the difference between the two online. Any help highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: So the official solution to the exercise is supposedly "Han salido de París en coche para poder llevar much equipaje"?  That sentence doesn't make sense to me as it stands.  Is it possible there were two different phrases, and the second one was just a fragment?  Also, it would be very helpful to see the whole original exercise, as it was given to you.  For each of the numbered blanks, was there a specific set of prepositions to choose from?  Finally, take a look at this related post: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/34/9385

Comment: According to my exercise (handout by my teacher) the correct solution is salir para Paris. There is no context, so just as @wimi said, I think it depends on how you interpret the sentence. And there wasn't a specific set of prepositions to choose from.

Comment: Mike - thanks.  It would be helpful to have the rest of the exercise -- because I'd like to see if the last part could be a fragment, or if it has to fit together with the earlier part, to make a whole sentence that hangs together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you found this on a textbook, the solution is incomplete. Both "salir de" and "salir para" are correct in that sentence, but with different meanings.

- Han salido de París en coche

means "They have left Paris by car", and

- Han salido para París en coche

means "They have left for Paris by car" (i.e., they have departed from somewhere else in the direction of Paris).

Comment: Perfect, makes total sense. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

salir para = go to
salir de = go from, basically, the diference is salir para Paris, means that Paris is the destination, salir de paris means that Paris is the origin